# Converting Algorithm from Python to C: Suggestions for Using bin() in C?

Tags: python, c

So essentially, I have a [homework](/questions/tagged/homework) problem to write in [c](/questions/tagged/c), and instead of taking the easy route, I thought that I would implement a little algorithm and some coding practice to impress my Professor. The question is to help us to pick up C (or review it, the former is for me), and the question tells us to return all of the integers that divide a given integer (such that there is no remainder).

What I did in [python](/questions/tagged/python) was to create a **is_prime()** method, a **pool_of_primes()** method, and a **combinations()** method. So far, I have everything done in C, up to the **combinations()** method. The problem that I am running into now is some syntax errors (i.e. not being able to alter a string by declaration) and mainly the [binary](/questions/tagged/binary) that I was using for the purpose of what would be included in my list of combinations. But without being able to alter my string by declaration, the Python code is kind of broken...

Here is the [python](/questions/tagged/python) code:

```
def combinations(aList):
    '''
        The idea is to provide a list of ints and combinations will provide
    all of the combinations of that list using binary.
        To track the combinations, we use a string representation of binary
    and count down from there. Each spot in the binary represents an
    on/off (included/excluded) indicator for the numbers.
    '''
    length      =   len(aList)  #Have this figured out
    s       =   ""
    canidates   =   0
    nList       =   []
    if (length >=21):
        print("\nTo many possible canidates for integers that divide our number.\n")
        return False
    for i in range(0,length):
        s       +=  "1"
        canidates   +=  pow(2,i)
    #We now have a string for on/off switch of the elements in our
    #new list. Canidates is the size of the new list.
    nList.append(1)
    while (canidates != 0):
        x   =   1
        for i in range(0,length):
            if(int(s[i]) == 1):
                x   =   x*aList[i]
        nList.append(x)
        canidates   -=  1
        s       =   ''
        temp        =   bin(canidates)
        for i in range(2,len(temp)):
            s   =   s+temp[i]
        if (len(s) != length):
                #This part is needed in cases of [1...000-1 = 0...111]
            while( len(s) != length):
                s   =   '0'+s
    return nList
```

Sorry if the entire code is to lengthy or not optimized to a specific suiting. But it works, and it works well :)

Again, I currently have everything that **aList** would have, stored as a singly-linked list in [c](/questions/tagged/c) (which I am able to print/use). I also have a little macro I included in C to convert binary to an integer:

```
#define B(x) S_to_binary_(#x)
static inline unsigned long long S_to_binary_(const char *s)
{
    unsigned long long i = 0;
    while (*s) {
        i <<= 1;
        i += *s++ - '0';
    }
    return i;
}
```

This may be Coder's Block setting in, but I am not seeing how I can change the binary in the same way that I did in Python... Any help would be greatly appreciated! Also, as a note, what is typically the best way to return a finalized code in C?

**EDIT:**

Accidentally took credit for the macro above.

## **UPDATE**

I just finished the code, and I [uploaded it onto Github](https://github.com/Twoody/integers_that_divide_me/blob/master/main.c). I would like to thank @nneonneo for providing the step that I needed to finish it with exemplary code.If anyone has any further suggestions about the code, I would be happy to see there ideas on [Github]!

Comment: I like the way you have tried to provide good context for your question, and have "done your homework" before asking.  However, I find your question almost intractable nonetheless.  The information is "all over the shop".  I wonder if you can "distill" the question further, and ask a more targetted question, without extraneous information.  While you are at it, I would never have a function called "S_to_binary_" return an int.  It's really "binary_string_to_int".

Comment: @GreenAsJade I apologize for that... I always try to offer as much detail at first just because some people can get pretty aggressive when not enough is provided. What do you think is to much? I would be happy to edit it out!

Comment: @T.Woody I have always found that examples of expected input and expected output to be quite helpful.  As it stands, we can see where you are, but not exactly where you want to be.

Comment: Heh heh you can't win :)   It looks like you have a pointer now, in an answer, about how to proceed, so you might not need to bother with a clean up.

Comment: Note that `combinations(aList)` produces duplicates if there are repeated factors in `aList`. True, you can weed out those dupes, but it's inefficient if you're looking for all the factors of a number that has lots of repeated prime factors. Eg, if the integer = 216 = 2**3 * 3**3, your algorithm produces 64 combinations, of which only 16 are unique. There is a way around this...

Comment: @PM2Ring, I realized this while writing the code (that's why I force it to break if the combinations exceed a certain amount). I saw some ways around it, but nothing that was take something else away. I do have a  `get_rid_of_doubles()`, too, that I left out because I felt it took away from the combinations point. What would you recommend?

Comment: You can adapt your algorithm to use a [mixed radix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mixed_radix) number instead of a binary number. It's fairly easy to write a Python generator that does mixed radix counting; my version is about a dozen very short lines. I've never bothered doing it in C, but it shouldn't be that much harder. If you need more info, *please* start a new question.

Comment: @PM2Ring, I see your point, but the binary part was a little bit faster than radix just because it is built into the language. I like your thinking outside of the box, though! Also, I have a finished product using binary and combinations that I uploaded (link in update), if you would like to check it out!

Comment: The mixed radix thing is easy to do in Python. I guess it'd be a little more tedious in C, but it's the most efficient algorithm I know. I was rather pleased when I first thought of it. :)  I just had a quick look at your C code on github. I'll have a closer look later, but I just noticed that you have an indentation error on lines 141-152. True, it doesn't matter in C, but it's nice to be neat. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why use a string at all? Keep it simple: use an integer, and use bitwise math to work with the number. Then you don't have to do any conversions back and forth. It will also be loads faster.

You can use a `uint32_t` to store the "bits", which is enough to hold 32 bits (since you max out at 21, this should work great).

For example, you can loop over the bits that are set by using a loop like this:

```
uint32_t my_number = ...;

for(int i=0; i<32; i++) {
    if(my_number & (1<<i)) {
        /* bit i is set */
    }
}
```

Comment: The only other time that I have seen <uint32_t> is briefly in my Compiler Construction course this week. I'll see what Google has to offer! Do you have any suggestions on the implementation of it in the mean tie?

Comment: This is your homework, not mine. I gave you some suggestions on a direction to proceed.

Comment: Touche. I didn't see your example listed prior. That should be enough!

Comment: @T.Woody: No, but I was providing an example of how to replace one of your loops with bitwise operations. There's still some code you'd have to implement outside of that, but if you can wrap your head around bitwise operations you'll find that you can actually write your code quite succinctly.